# Best practice for changing desktop environment

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, desktop-environments

I'm thinking of switching from plasma to gnome, but because I'm running on kubuntu, I'm not sure if the best way to transition is to install gnome over kubuntu or reinstall ubuntu gnome from zero. My home folder is on a different partition, so I'm not worried to lose any data (plus everything is also backup-ed).

In addition I was wondering if there were any other good practices to follow when switching DE?

[Specifics]

current DE: Plasma 5.21.4

OS: Kubuntu 21.04

Linux Kernel Version: 5.11.0-37-generic

Comment: You haven't provided release details (there can be slight differences between releases), but personally I'm a lover of multiple desktops on my installs - so if it was me I'd just install `ubuntu-desktop` & have KDE/Plasma & GNOME as choices.  Of course every choice has pros & cons - so this option won't be best for everyone...   You can re-install a Ubuntu *flavor* without loss of files even if you're not using a separate partition (and destroy all partitions if not careful even if multiple partitions are used) with this a *testcase* for Lubuntu but isn't limited just to that *flavor*.

Comment: I consider many things, including release you're going from, release you're going to, toolkits/libraries involved in the change of DE, packages [*manually*] installed, programs you're going to keep, experience of the end-users (multiple DEs adds complexity which isn't nice for newbies) & a lot of other items - none of which you've provided in your question. To me your question is asking for opinions (which aren't well suited to this Q&A site - best on forums).